# How can I justify rich text with in Google Colab Markdown?

Tags: markdown, google-colaboratory, justify, text-justify

When I use this in text cell in Google Colaboratory:

```
<p align="justify">
Some plain texts will be aligned justify
</p>
```

to plain text it works just fine, but when text e.g gets bolded or gets hyperlinks then it doesen't work properly.
(like in section "Justify" [here](https://colab.research.google.com/github/Tanu-N-Prabhu/Python/blob/master/Cheat_sheet_for_Google_Colab.ipynb) - *link to Cheat-sheet_for_Google_Colab*).

I am new to this.

Any suggestions will be appreaciated!

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Actually you don't need to write the closing part `<\p>` for this, the important thing is to use the open bracket `<p align="justify">` before the text you want to display. The only issue is that you have to repeat the same header for each new paragraph. Another important thing is to write the text right after the header code, if you use a break line, then the header will not apply to your text. that is, You have to write:

`<p align="justify">First paragraph`

`<p align="justify">New paragraph`